# Bash: How to read multiline options from olsrd config (nginx similar)

Tags: bash, parsing, nginx, config, olsrd

How do you parse (and modify) following config: (extract from olsrd.conf)

```
Hna4
{
4.3.2.1 255.255.255.255
#   Internet gateway:
#   0.0.0.0      0.0.0.0
#   more entries can be added:
#   192.168.1.0  255.255.255.0
1.2.3.4 255.255.255.255
2.3.4.5 255.255.255.255
}
```

I would need this config (stored in a bash variable) in this format:

```
1.2.3.4 255.255.255.255;2.3.4.5 255.255.255.255
```

And also would need this to write back from this format to the olsrd.conf file.

(it's similar to nginx config, just that the brackets begin in next line.)

After some research i came up with using grep to find the linenumber of "Hna4" in olsrd.conf, then from this point on find the linenumber of the first closing bracket, then get all lines between those two linenumbers, then parse content..

Is there some other(better) way to achieve this?

Comment: why did i get a downvote? for what reason? i would like to understand that..

Comment: You mention that you "came up with using grep"m but you did not include this code/script into the question. Please always add what you did (the most relevant part at least) to the question.

Answer (score 1):

With sed :

```
$ ips=$(sed -n '/Hna4/,/}/ { /^ *\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}/ { N ;/^ *\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}/ s/\n/;/ p } } ' < sourcefile)
$ echo $ips
1.2.3.4 255.255.255.255;2.3.4.5 255.255.255.255
```

**Update :**

To output all ip :

```
$ ips=$(sed -n '/Hna4/,/}/ { /}/! { /^ *\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}/ { H } };/}/ { x; s/\n/;/g; s/^;//; s/\n}//; p }}' file)
$ echo $ips
4.3.2.1 255.255.255.255;1.2.3.4 255.255.255.255;2.3.4.5 255.255.255.255
```

Comment: thanks, that works, but not if for example an ip is added in the beginning of this option. i updated the question. the output would be:

    4.3.2.1 255.255.255.255;# Internet gateway: 1.2.3.4 255.255.255.255;2.3.4.5 255.255.255.255